# How do I repeat images and textboxes as headers for each report sheet in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have multiple datasets that I am binding to individual tablixes in order to render them as individual Excel workbook sheets. However, I need the header elements that are visible on the very first sheet, to be repeated on all of the other sheets, in exactly the same format and position. How will I go about doing this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containing all the elements within a rectangle element solved the issue.

Comment: I think both are great answers ;) haha

Answer (score 0):

Simply place them wherever you'd like to see them; there may exist a more elegant approach but this has always worked for me, just remember to add a page break before every header and ensure there is no "blank"spacing between sheets.

Comment: Might I add that the header elements are individual images and textboxes. Will your idea still apply?

Comment: I ended up adding the individual elements into a rectangle which allowed the grouping to be more precise.

Comment: beautiful, so you treated the rectangle as the parent and were able to contain everything within it? NIce!